# base class initialization error, no matching constructor

Tags: c++

First and foremost I'd like to apologize for the magnitude of code I'm dumping. I'm writing some code that allows the user to withdraw and deposit money into an account, the code also calculates the interest rate of the account and the number of withdrawals and deposits etc. I get on error when I try to call the base class functions to the child functions, "no matching constructor." I can't seem to find a problem with the constructors on my own. Can anyone help?

Account.cpp

```
#include "Account.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


//overloaded constructor
Account::Account(double accBal, double annIntRate){
  accBal = accBal;
  annIntRate = annIntRate;
};

//deposit base class function
int Account::deposit(double accBal, int numWithdrawal)
{
  cout << "Enter deposit: "<< endl;
  double depos;
  cin >> depos;
  accBal += depos;
  numDepos ++;
  return accBal;
}

//withdraw base class function
void Account::withdraw(double accBal, int numWithdrawal)
{
  double amount; 
  cin >> amount;
  accBal -= amount;
  numWithdrawal ++; 
}

//interest rate calculation
void Account::calcInt(double accBal, double annIntRate)
{
  double monthlyIntRate = annIntRate/2;
  double monthlyInt = accBal * monthlyIntRate;
  accBal += monthlyInt;

}
```

Account.h

```
    #ifndef ACCOUNT_H
#define ACCOUNT_H

class Account
{
  //variable declarations
  private:
  
  int accNum;
  double accBal;
  int numWithdrawal;
  int numDepos;
  double annIntRate;
  double monthServCharg;
  
  public:

  Account(double, double); //overloaded constructor
  
  virtual int deposit(double, int); //base class deposit declaration 
  
  virtual void withdraw(double, int); //base class withdraw declaration
  
  virtual void calcInt(double, double); //updates interest rate
  
  void setAccNum(int); //setter
  int getAccNum(){return accNum;} //getter

  void setAccBal(double);//setter
  double getAccBal(){return accBal;}//getter

  void setNumWithdrawal(int);//setter
  int getNumWithdrawal(){return numWithdrawal;}//getter

  void setNumDep(int);//setter
  int getNumDep(){return numDepos;}//getter

  void setAnnIntRate(double);//setter
  double getAnnIntRate(){return annIntRate;}//getter

  void setMonthServCharg(double); //setter
  double getMonthServCharg(){return monthServCharg;}//getter
};
#endif
```

SavingsAccount.cpp

```
#include "SavingsAcc.h"
#include "Account.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//status constructor
SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount(bool status)
{
  status = false;
}

//deposit money function
void SavingsAccount::deposit(bool status, double accBal, int numDepos) 
{
  Account obj;
  obj.deposit(accBal);   //PROBLEM

  if (accBal > 25.00)
  status = true;
  else 
  status = false;
}

//withdraw money child function, updates account status, service charges, interest rate etc
void SavingsAccount::withdraw(double accBal, int numWithdrawal, double annIntRate, double monthServCharg) 
{
  double amount;
  if (accBal <= 25.00)
  cout << "Balance too low, withdrawals cannot be made at this time"<<endl;
  else
  {
    do
    { 
      Account obj;
      obj.withdraw(numWithdrawal); // PROBLEM
      
      if (numWithdrawal > 4)
      monthServCharg += 1;

      if (accBal < 25.00)
      {annIntRate += 0.01;}
    }
    while (amount > accBal);
    cout << "Insufficient funds!";
  }
   
}

//outputs the report of account 
void SavingsAccount::accountReport(int accNum, bool status, int numWithdrawal, int numDepos, double monthServeCharg, double accBal)
{
  
  cout << "====ACCOUNT STATUS===="<<endl;
  cout << "Account number: "<< accNum <<endl;
  
  if (status == true) //status 
  cout << "Satus: Active" << endl;
  else 
  cout <<"Status: Inactive" << endl;

  cout << "Total deposits: "<< numDepos << endl;
  cout << "Total withdrawals" << numWithdrawal << endl;
  cout << "Service charges: "<< monthServeCharg << endl;
  cout << "Balance: "<<accBal<<endl;

}
```

SavingsAccount.h

```
#ifndef SAVINGSACC_H
#define SAVINGSACC_H
#include <iostream>

class SavingsAccount: public Account
{
  private:
   
    bool status; //status variable
  
  public:

  SavingsAccount(bool); // constuctor
  
  void deposit(bool, double, int); // deposit function
  
  void withdraw(double, int, double, double); //withdraw function

  void accountReport(int, bool, int, int, double, double ); // full report of account
};
#endif
```

Comment: please show the location where the compiler gives you the error/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor

```
Account(double, double); //overloaded constructor
```

is actually not overloading constructor but invalidating the default constructor.

To use this constructor, passing values for the arguments when constructing `SavingsAccount` like

```
SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount(bool status) : Account(42, 334)
{
  status = false;
}
```

is required.

Also the line

```
obj.deposit(accBal);   //PROBLEM
```

is causing error because the class Account doesn't have function deposit that takes only one argument. You should delete the line or pass right number of arguments to resolve this error.